# OpenCV Crashes on imShow only for usb webcam

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, window, video-capture

I am attempting to get openCV setup with Qt.  I am using Qt creator although I currently am only making C++/opencv calls.  This code works fine with my integrated webcam however when I switch to my usb camera I get a windows error telling me opencv.exe has crashed and Qt tells me my program finished unexpectedly.  Interestingly enough if I change imshow to imwrite I get output from the webcam in a file so the the capture seems to work I just cant display.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    // open the default camera, use something different from 0 otherwise;
    // Check VideoCapture documentation.
    if(!cap.isOpened())
        return 1;

    for(;;)
    {
          Mat frame;
          cap.retrieve(frame);
          if( frame.empty() ) break; // end of video stream

          imshow("this is you, smile! :)", frame);
          if( waitKey(1) == 27 ) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC
    }
    // the camera will be closed automatically upon exit
    // cap.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that when you use your usb cam, you change arguments to VideoCapture cap(1) instead of cap(0). cap(1) is your usb camera driver that may require separate installation. Try cap(2) or cap(3), and see if you get an output on imshow, via the usb camera.

In case that doesn't help, replace

```
cap.retrieve(frame);
```

with

```
cap>>frame;
```

Comment: Yes forgot to mention that I do change from cap(0) to cap(1). actually depending if the usb camera is in when I boot its cap(0) and my integrated  camera is cap(1).  no luck changing to 2 or 3 they exit at the !cap.isOpened() call.  Ill try reinstalling drivers. although I think they are working since I can write frames to a file